# Webpack 2 html-webpack-plugin (SystemJS) ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-2

I'm having this issue, the project is good until I have push in repository, now the project which is working in my machine is not working when I clone from repository in another directory or in other machine.

I have tried fixing this issue with `npm cache clean` or even removing node_modules completely and reinstalling dependencies but no luck

***Running on***:
*Webpack version: 2.1.0-beta.25

Environment: OS X 10.11.6

Node v6.2.0, npm 3.8.9*

***npm debug file:***

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@3.8.9
3 info using node@v6.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~prebuild: betconsole@1.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~prebuild: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~prebuild: PATH: /Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/armend/Dropbox/htdocs/testapp/betconsole/node_modules/.bin:/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin:/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
8 verbose lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~prebuild: CWD: /Users/armend/Dropbox/htdocs/testapp/betconsole
9 silly lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~prebuild: Args: [ '-c', 'rimraf dist' ]
10 silly lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~prebuild: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~build: betconsole@1.0.0
12 verbose lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~build: PATH: /Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/armend/Dropbox/htdocs/testapp/betconsole/node_modules/.bin:/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin:/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
14 verbose lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/armend/Dropbox/htdocs/testapp/betconsole
15 silly lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack --env.prod -p' ]
16 silly lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
17 info lifecycle betconsole@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
18 verbose stack Error: betconsole@1.0.0 build: `webpack --env.prod -p`
18 verbose stack Exit status 2
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:245:16)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
19 verbose pkgid betconsole@1.0.0
20 verbose cwd /Users/armend/Dropbox/htdocs/testapp/betconsole
21 error Darwin 15.6.0
22 error argv "/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/armend/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
23 error node v6.2.0
24 error npm  v3.8.9
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error betconsole@1.0.0 build: `webpack --env.prod -p`
26 error Exit status 2
27 error Failed at the betconsole@1.0.0 build script 'webpack --env.prod -p'.
27 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
27 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the betconsole package,
27 error not with npm itself.
27 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
27 error     webpack --env.prod -p
27 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
27 error     npm bugs betconsole
27 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
27 error     npm owner ls betconsole
27 error There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

[image: Screenshot Top]

[image: Screenshot Bottom]

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is facing with the same issue, problem was solved downgrading `postcss-import` to `8.1.0`.